# Running a custom termination of a process in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, global-variables, python-multiprocessing, terminate

There may be a simple way to do this, but I am relatively new to python. Essentially, I have two functions in different files. One creates a new process to run the other. However, upon user key stroke (enter key) I would like to send a signal to terminate the other process. However, prior to termination, I would want that process to run some sort of save function then terminate, therefore I cannot use multiprocessing's built-in terminate.

Here's the example code from file 1:

```
import test_global
import msvcrt
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = mp.Process(target=test_global.test)
    process.start()
    
    while True:
        #Emergency Stop
        #Detect user key input
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            #Detect enter key
            if msvcrt.getwche() == '\r':
                #Emergency function stop
                test_global.emergency_stop = True
                print("Emergency Stop Activated")
                print("Clock Stopped")
                break
```

And the example code from the file "test_global" of the process its running:

```
import time as t
import datetime as dt

global emergency_stop
emergency_stop = False

def test():
    while True:
        print(f"No input. {dt.datetime.now()}")
        if emergency_stop:
            save()
            print("function stopped")
            break
        t.sleep(1)


def save():
    """
    Do some save things here
    """
    pass
```

As you can see, I tried to edit test_global's global variable "emergency_stop" in order to do this. I have thought of using pipes and queues, but then the main process will constantly need to send None until the emergency stop is activated. A queue would be possible, but then the process will constantly need to clear it in search of the actual emergency_stop. I could pickle a variable and read said pickle, but this also seems overly complex, and a bit time consuming.

Comment: "have thought of using pipes and queues, but then the main process will constantly need to send None until the emergency stop is activated." It is not True!

Comment: You don't have to keep sending things to the queue! All you need to do is send a stop signal in the main process and read it in the child process and stop the process
Moreover, for this it is not necessary to use queues, Variable or Event is enough